# Google Sitelinks don't appear with the domain in some search cases

Tags: utf-8, seo, arabic, google-search

I'm facing a weird problem with Google search , when I search for my website using these keywords "dardasha newspaper" ... I got the expected correct result. my site comes first with site-links included.
[https://www.google.com/search?q=dardasha+newspaper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=dardasha%20newspaper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

But when I search for my website using these keywords "جريدة دردشة", I got the correct result but with no site-links
[https://www.google.com/search?q=dardasha+newspaper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9+%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%B4%D8%A9](https://www.google.com/search?q=dardasha%20newspaper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%B4%D8%A9)

Even my website's language is "Arabic" - the second one used for the search. ... Why are the search results different based on used keywords?

Answer (score 0):

The results are expanded to site-links in Google results when you search by website domain or very close.

Your website is `www.dardashanewspaper.com` and you searched by `dardasha newspaper` which is the domain name.

Another problem is that Google thinks that dardasha in Arabic is : [درداشا](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=strict&q=%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%A7&oq=%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%A7&gs_l=serp.3...1965.5735.0.6541.3.3.0.0.0.0.666.1043.0j2j5-1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..3.0.0.FEi5l9R5Og4&safe=high) not دردشة.